# Get Index of Activated Tab

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm upgrading code from jQuery UI 1.8 to 1.10.

Under 1.8, the event triggered when the tab changes was `select`, and I could access the index of the tab being selected through `ui.index`.

Under 1.10, the event triggered when the tab changes is `activate`.  However, I cannot find anything in the event parameter `ui` that tells me the index of the newly activated tab.

How can I discover that index?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use the following approach http://jsfiddle.net/9ChL5/1/:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    activate: function (event, ui) {

        console.log(ui.newTab.index());
    }
});
```

Comment: Was just curious if there was documentation on the JQuery UI site for .index() or any of the other properties available.  I saw that the ui object had newTab/oldTab/newPanel/oldPanel as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15367388/684617).  But I didn't see further detail as to the existence of other properties, at least on that page.

Comment: @GoldDragonTSU `ui.newTab` is a regular jQuery object here and `index()` is jQuery's [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) (indicated by "Type: jQuery" in the [activate event docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate)).

Answer (score 0):

The UI object is still here but seems to hold directly the jQuery objects of oldTab, newTab, oldPanel, newPanel, so you don't need the index to find the object you want to use.

See http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

```
ui Type: Object

- newTab
Type: jQuery
The tab that was just activated.
- oldTab
Type: jQuery
The tab that was just deactivated.
- newPanel
Type: jQuery
The panel that was just activated.
- oldPanel
Type: jQuery
The panel that was just deactivated.
```

Comment: I do need the index because I'm saving the active index as a user preference in the database.