# Return index of currently open tab

Tags: javascript, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have some logic which refreshes a portion of my page after I enter some data. The data entry form is on the second tab of a three tab table. When one tab is open the other two are closed.

When I enter the data, the refresh function closes the second tab and opens the first one again, I want the second tab to remain open.

I'm looking for a way of getting the index of the currently open tab which I think will put me on the right path to solving this problem.

So how do I get the index of the currently open tab?

Someone has already asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367234/get-index-of-activated-tab) but I can't seem to get the answer to work for me!

```
 var index;

 jQuery("#tabs").tabs({
     activate: function (event, ui) {
     index = (ui.newTab.index());
     }
 });
```

Comment: Can you post a demo to give us an idea of why it doesn't work? Explain what's going wrong, or what you expect/want that isn't being achieved. Show us your relevant code (HTML, CSS as well as the jQuery).

Comment: Ah, I actually think ui.index is undefined as of jQuery UI 1.9...

Comment: @Daft: I just tested your code, and it seems to work fine for me. http://jsbin.com/winuwego/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some more searching online and some trial and error, I found this works perfectly for me.

```
 var tab_idx;           

 function getSelectedTabIndex() { 
    return jQuery("#tabs").tabs('option', 'active');
 }

 tab_idx = getSelectedTabIndex();
```